# how do i understand the encoding for the latitude and longitude for the here fleet telematics api? (e.g layer. ROAD_GEOM_FC5)

Tags: here-api

In the fleet telematic api for HERE developers, it says the latitude and longitude is encoded. I can see that the lat and lon is shorted and seperated by commas with other numbers. What does this actually mean?
This is taken from layer ROAD_GEOM_FC5.

```
 {
            "LINK_ID": "23990186",
            "LONG_HAUL": "N",
            "NAME": "Rayen St",
            "NAMES": "ENGBNRayen St",
            "TUNNEL": "N",
            "BRIDGE": "N",
            "LAT": "3423096,11,16,,4,13",
            "LON": "-11864784,-5,-33,-61,-9,-9",
            "ZLEVEL": ",,,,,"
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

LAT: Latitude coordinates [10^-5 degree WGS84] along the polyline. Comma separated. Each value is relative to the previous.

LON: Longitude coordinates [10^-5 degree WGS84] along the polyline. Comma separated. Each value is relative to the previous.

Details please check [here](https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=WEU&release=20111&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=ROAD_GEOM_FC5).

Comment: it says the page im looking for doesn't exist

Comment: Could you try login first at https://tcs.ext.here.com/login with your Freemium account, and then try to open the page again?

Comment: i tried logging in to traffic analytics tool or traffic viewer and its not letting me through? I was able to login to my here projects with my freemium acct.